# Preserving the order of a sequence of real numbers

Tags: inequality

If a have a sequence of real numbers ordered from greatest to smallest $Y_o\geq Y_1 \geq...\geq Y_k$ and I divide each number of the sequence by $\delta<0$, is the order of the sequence flipped, i.e. $\frac{Y_0}{\delta}\leq \frac{Y_1}{\delta}\leq...\leq \frac{Y_k}{\delta}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, multiplying or dividing by negative numbers reverses inequalities. On the other hand, multiplying or dividing by positive numbers preserves inequalities.